# Actionscript 3.0 - Clear function that serves as a button to press then empties the input text when it is filled

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Can anyone help me solve my problem in AS3?
(P.S I wanted to have a clear button that will minimize the time spent in using this simple calculator :) )

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, crazywaltz. Just so you know, you need a lot more detail in your question from now on - platform, goal, current relevant code (what have you tried?). Put info mostly in your question, not in your title.

You also need to do your own research in the future. Google is a great resource! The documentation for AS3 is also available online, so read that. You could have found your answer in just a few minutes that way. People on StackOverflow do not like answering questions like this, and you won't get good answers usually.

That said, I'll help you out this first time. The code to clear a text field is as follows. I'm assuming your clear button is called btnClear, and your text box is called myTextField.

```
btnClear.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clearText);

function clearText(evt:MouseEvent)
{
    myTextField.text = "";
}
```

It is up to you to find out how this code works, and how to add buttons and text fields to your stage.

Comment: Sir I wanted to post my code but I can't I don't know how to indent in this website and its my first time here

Comment: You have to use multiple spaces instead of tabs here. Kind of odd. That said, if you copy and paste, indents are usually preserved. Then, highlight your code in your post and click the button with the brackets {} to mark the selection as code.